# How do you load an image from ftp and handling it with picasso library?

Tags: android, picasso

I want to load an image from my ftp server and show it with `picasso` library.
Is it possible ?
This is my code code but `.load()` does not accept `InputStream`. Any suggestions?

```
try {

          FTPClient mFTPClient = new FTPClient();
          mFTPClient.connect("ftp.server.com");      
          mFTPClient.login("user","pass");
          mFTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
          mFTPClient.changeWorkingDirectory("/public_ftp/");
          inStream = mFTPClient.retrieveFileStream("18.jpg");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println( "Error communicating with FTP server." );
        }
         Picasso.with(this)
        .load(inStream)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.local_wallpaper) 
        .resize(200, 200)
        .centerInside()
        .into(mc, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess() {
                                Log.v("", "success");

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError() {
                                Log.v("", "Error");
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: Have you tried using the ftp url for `.load`?

Comment: @ShashwatBlack yes it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

As Damien said, it looks like this is not possible with `picasso`.

Here are a few suggestions you can try,

1. Download the ftp image using some other tools, and load the picture from memory. But this would blemish a very important feature of `picasso` - image caching. If you want that, you'll have to write code for that by yourself.
2. Create a module in your server to get the ftp image and dump it as regular one using `http` protocol.
3. Dnkutso suggests [here](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/990) about using custom `RequestHandler`. But I couldn't tell you anything more about it.